# android application icon is no longer seen on device

Tags: android, react-native

Android icon is no longer seen on device. (seeing default android icon instead)

I'm using the following command as always: `react-native run-android --variant=release`,

Today I've been getting errors while trying to run the app figuring out I was needed to add `multiDexEnabled` to my `build.gradle` file.

the icons files still exist under the `mipmap` directory.

`build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 14
        versionName "0.2.3"
        multiDexEnabled true <------- This one is new
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="oauthlogin" android:host="login" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</application>
```

I'm seeing the default android icon instead of my own `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. And I have no lead on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your icon in drawable folder and also change the icon name like `@drawable/app_icon`
May it will work for you

Comment: Can't believe that it was just a cache.. i've just renamed the image.. Thanks!